# Slider with images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, uislider

I need a html slider like a selectToUISlider. But it should contain images instead of a text values. Could you please a recomend smth? I was searching through the Internet but without any result. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend jQuery.Cycle: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Comment: You don't understand what I need. Please, look at the picture. http://xmages.net/storage/10/1/0/7/0/upload/49d422c7.png